# Keras clear all gpu memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory

I'm doing something like this:

```
for ai in ai_generator:
   ai.fit(ecc...)
```

ai_generator is a generator that instantiate a model with different configuration.
My problem is gpu memory overflow, and K.clear_session() don't work because it throw this
 `ValueError: Tensor("conv2d_1/kernel:0", shape=(3, 3, 1, 1), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("concat:0", shape=(?, 38, 300, 1), dtype=float32).`
How can I clear keras memory as new?
I need only performances of fit method, I can delete all.

Comment: You could try `del model`

Comment: I did it, I discover that the same imput layer was used for instantiate all models. so maybe the gc didn't delete any because was connected to an "alive" instance. Thank you very much for your reply^.^ 
`ai.fit( **params)
  del ai
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  K.clear_session()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved removing all layer shared between models. The "shared" instance was the input.
Then I did this:

```
for ai in aigen:
   ai.fit(**params)
   del ai #  for avoid any trace on aigen
   tf.reset_default_graph() # for being sure
   K.clear_session() # removing session, it will instance another
```

Comment: when writing k.clear_session() do you mean keras.backend.clear_session()

Comment: Yes, I did `import keras.backend as K`